# Batch file programming

Tags: batch-file

I am new to batch file programming.
My requirement is to provide a prompt to the user to select a file type like (.xml or .conf).Once user gives the input, batch file will search in "D:\abc" folder which may have many sub directories and copy those files at some other location but in the same folders as they were in the source folders.
e.g if source of the .xml file is "D:\abc\bb\d.xml" it should paste that file in "D:\backup\abc\bb\d.xml"

Thanks
VG

Comment: I just tried this @echo off
for /R D:\Splunk %%f in (*.xml) do copy %%f d:\test
pause  but with this all the .xml files are pasted in one folder

Comment: I achieved this xcopy d:\splunk\*.conf d:\test\  /s/y  with this it search and paste the file recursively I just left with one thing that is providing propmt

Comment: Run in a command prompt window `set /?` and read about `set /P`. And simply read some questions and answers with the tag **batch-file** as there are thousands of batch codes with user input. Example [Why can a user set a new password without the need to enter old password correct with my batch code?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25824539)

Answer (score 0):

SET /P would be an easy solution to your problem, but if you used CHOICE, you wouldn't have to press enter to confirm the key press.

Example of CHOICE: CHOICE /T [Number of countdown seconds until the default key is chosen] /C [Insert possible keys pressed] /N [Hides keys prompt] /D [Specifies to count for /T seconds. Any key or number after /D is the default choice] /CS [Case-sensitive?] /M [Message to display]

CHOICE returns an ERRORLEVEL value upon execution, with an ERRORLEVEL of 1 if the person pressed the last option key, 2 for the second-last and so on. You can detect the errorlevel with IF %errorlevel% equ [n].

Use CHOICE with a loop which cycles through all of the file endings that you want.