# Batch file keeps saying goto is unexpected

Tags: batch-file

Whenever I do use this, it says goto is unexpected. Why? I've looked through many of the answered questions here and it seems like I can not seem to get it right. Also, no matter what input I make, whether it is correct or not, it seems to go to :incorrect. Help please.

```
@echo off
:password
set /p pw=Type password:
if %pw%=="fdDg*3&d@%jdgf" goto begin
if not %pw%=="fdDg*3&d@%jdgf" goto incorrect
:incorrect
echo Access denied.
goto password
:begin
echo Welcome!
pause
exit
```

Comment: try this : `if "%pw%"=="fdDg*3&d@%jdgf"`

Comment: if you run your script with `echo on`, you'll notice, that it doesn't like the percent-sign in your password. The `if not ....` line is not needed.

Comment: I have removed the if not statement and changed the percent signs. However, it still displays any input as incorrect. I just need to figure out how to make it so if one value is inputted, it works. If other values are inputted, it goes to :incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
@echo off
:password
set /p "pw=Type password: "
if "%pw%"=="fdDg*3&d@%%jdgf" goto begin
:incorrect
echo Access denied.
goto password
:begin
echo Welcome!
pause
exit
```

For the case-sensitive comparison of entered password by predefined password surrounding double quotes are needed as [Kayasax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/381149/kayasax) wrote.

The percent sign has a special meaning as you can see it because you use the special meaning on `%pw%`. Therefore the percent sign in password string must be escaped with one more percent sign as [Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152082/stephan) mentioned. And the `if not` line is really not needed.

However, the password verification code still needs more code for checking on invalid input, see answer on [Why can a user set a new password without the need to enter old password correct with my batch code?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25826667/3074564)